# Incrementing Bash Variable inside programmatically opened terminal

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "

while true
do
count=\$(expr $(count+1))
echo \$count


done

;bash"
```

I'm unable to increment count variable when I open terminal programmatically. It increments once only with the above code.

Comment: You forgot to escape the `$` in the nested command substitution. You don't need `expr`, by the way; `while true; do count=\$((count + 1)); echo \$count; done` will work

Comment: using bash: `while true; do echo $((count+=1)); done` but what's the point? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you escaping the "\$?"